# Как получить фактические PTS и DTS после декодирования кадров с помощью libavcodec FFmpeg

Tags: c++, видео, ffmpeg, decode

C++, FFmpeg, libavcodec, декодирование видеокадров.

Чтобы разобрать данные из сети и разбить их на кадры, я использую функцию `av_parser_parse2(_parser, _context, &_packet_encoded_frame->data, &_packet_encoded_frame->size, data, data_size, pts ? pts : AV_NOPTS_VALUE, dts ? dts : AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0)` которой я передаю ненулевые значения PTS и DTS (считанные из заголовка PES пакета) в качестве входных данных.

Затем я использую функции `avcodec_send_packet(_context, _packet_encoded_frame)` и `avcodec_receive_frame(_context, _frame)` для декодирования кадров.

Почему у меня ВСЕГДА PTS(`_frame->pts`) и DTS(`_frame->pkt_dts`) равны AV_NOPTS_VALUE после УСПЕШНОГО декодирования кадра? Как я могу получить фактические значения PTS и DTS этого кадра после декодирования кадра? Что я делаю не так?

Возможно мне нужно задавать значения PTS и DTS не в том месте, но ведь именно функция `av_parser_parse2` отвечает за разбор входных данных и разбиение на отдельные кадры. И зачем вообще в ней в качестве входных параметров PTS и DTS, если не для дальнейшего использования этих значений для декодирования? А если задавать эти значения не в функции `av_parser_parse2`, то где? И откуда мне в том месте взять значения для отдельных кадров?

Comment: это не точный ответ, так как я сам в поиске решения и некто не может мне подсказать. Вы можете пройти по ссылке и там есть небольшой ответ для варианта подумать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1548174/ffmpeg-c-Не-правильно-воспроизводит-видео-записанное-в-файл

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47549940/4711135